# Azure Front Door Service Diagnostics - region mismatch

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-front-door

I am trying to configure a storage account within the diagnostics settings for an Azure Front Door Service.

I get the following error message

```
Failed to update diagnostics for 'name_of_front_door_service'
{
    "code":"BadRequest",
    "message":"Resources should be in the same region. Resource 'resource_front_door_service' is in region 'global' and resource 'resource_storage_account' is in region 'region_of_storage_account'."
}.
```

Am I missing something...?

Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Front Door Service is still in **preview** version, seems the **Diagnostics settings** is not general available. I can reproduce your issue on my side, if we use `Archive to a storage account` or `Stream to an event hub`, both get the error message. Choose `Send to Log Analytics`, it works fine.

[See this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-diagnostic-logs-schema) for **a complete list of supported services and the log categories and schemas used by those services**. We can also find the Azure Front Door Service is **not** in the supported list.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.